# How to use FlatFileItemReader in spring batch for items separated by space (multiple records on single line)?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

Spring batch FlatFileItemReader supports two files formats by default, Fix length and delimiter separated. e.g

```
id name email 
1  name1  name1@abc.com
2  name2  name@abc.com
```

So it will consider each line as an item and fields as properties of item (domain) object.

My input file has just ids separated by space or comma as I just need ids (or it could be anything unique for each item like username or email etc) e.g

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9, ...... so on
```

or

```
username1, username2, username3, username4 .. so on
```

How can I use FlatFileItemReader to consider each id as an each item i.e in short multiple records on single line ? Or is there any other way to achive this ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use your custom `LineMapper` to implement the logic as per your requirement to separate the items from each line.

Here is the sample code that will return the list of Ids either separated by comma or space or both in each line.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;

public class CustomLineMapper implements LineMapper<List<String>> {

    public List<String> mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s1 : line.split(",")) {
            for (String s2 : s1.trim().split(" ")) {
                list.add(s2.trim());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how it would work in case of restart ? It will start every time from beginning ?

Comment: When one line is passed, LineMapper is supposed to return one record ( domain object) but in my case, in one line I have multiple records separated by command, I dont have fields (or I can say I have only one field).

Comment: Is there any way to configure LINE_SEPARATOR for flatfileitemreader so that it considers each comma separated item as each line ?

Comment: `FlatFileItemReader` uses [RecordSeparatorPolicy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/RecordSeparatorPolicy.html). Try with your custom `RecordSeparatorPolicy`.

Comment: My `CustomLineMapper ` is returning multiple records formed by a line. Isn't it?

Comment: `LINE_SEPARATOR` is a property of `FlatFileItemWriter`.

Comment: Look at the source code of different impl of `RecordSeparatorPolicy`. you will get an idea to impl of your custom `RecordSeparatorPolicy`.

Comment: It works but to myItemWriter, spring batch doesn't send items separately. It sends string of command separated items (ids). It should ideally send List of number of items equal to commit-interval.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50622/discussion-between-braj-and-user1191081)

Answer (score 0):

overriding default buffered reader can also solve this issue. So, in your custom reader, you don't proceed to next line if you haven't finished reading all objects in same line.